# Coq fails an apply tactic

Tags: apply, coq, coq-tactic

I am trying to prove the following simple theorem over natural numbers:

```
((i + j) = (i + k)) -> (j = k)
```

Here is what I have in `Coq`:

```
Theorem cancel : forall (i j k : nat),
  ((add i j) = (add i k)) -> (j = k).
Proof.
intros i j k.
induction i.
simpl.
apply A_IMPLIES_A.
simpl.
```

And after that I have the sub-goal:

```
S (add i j) = S (add i k) -> j = k
```

So I thought I'd apply `eq_add_S` which states that `S m = S n -> m = n`.
However, when I try to do so with `apply eq_add_S` I get the following error:

```
Error:
In environment
i, j, k : nat
IHi : add i j = add i k -> j = k
Unable to unify "k" with "add i k".
```

So I guess it can't understand that I want is `m = (add i j)` and `n = (add i k)`. How come `Coq` can't read my mind? or more seriously, how can I help him do so? thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not that Coq can't guess what value to use for `m` and `n`, but that your goal does not have the right shape for you to instantiate that theorem. When you write `apply eq_add_S`, Coq tries to unify `S n = S m -> n = m` with `S (add i j) = S (add i k) -> j = k`, which cannot be done.

What you need is to apply `eq_add_S` to the goal's *premise*, by introducing it into the context.

```
Proof.
intros i j k H. (* H : add i j = add i k *)
induction i as [|i IH].
- apply H.
- apply eq_add_S in H.
  (* ...  *)
```

Comment: This is probably a trivial question, but where is H defined? I mean I see it in the comment, but how can I actually define it?

Comment: In Coq jargon, the `intros ... H` tactic _introduces_ the `add i j = add i k`  premise from the goal into the context, giving it the name `H`.

Comment: I'm a bit confused, I thought H should be: `S (add i j) = S (add i k) -> (add i j) = (add i k)` no? any chance you can fill in the missing details? It seems that simple Coq examples are pretty hard to find online ... thanks!

Comment: No, what you wrote is the particular instance of the `eq_add_S` lemma that you need to complete the proof. It is what Coq produces after executing `apply eq_add_S in H.`.  I think the easiest thing for you would be to go over the Software Foundations book (https://softwarefoundations.cis.upenn.edu/). It is long, but filled with examples, including simple and complex.

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting the solution as a separate answer hoping other users can benefit from it. Here it is:

```
Theorem cancel : forall (i j k : nat),
  ((add i j) = (add i k)) -> (j = k).
Proof.
intros i j k H.
induction i.
apply H.
simpl in H.
apply eq_add_S in H.
apply IHi in H.
assumption.
Qed.
```